# Glassfish 3 - gzip compression does not work for .jsp

Tags: jsp, netbeans, glassfish, gzip

**Please watch this short video which shows my problem in detail**: http://youtu.be/uAza4m3fxpY?hd=1

I have a Glassfish 3.1 server running a Netbeans Web Project.
I have a very simple .jsp file with content type set to 'text/html' and a large paragraph of dummy text in the body. It looks like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Gzip Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Gzip compsression test</h1>
        <p>****LOTS OF DUMMY TEXT***</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Glassfish admin, I have forced-enabled gzip compression for the HTTP listener (as described in this guide: http://www.vikasing.com/2010/01/enable-gzip-compression-on-glassfish-v3.html)

When load the page in Firefox and look at the response header, I would expect to see `Content-Encoding: gzip`, but it's not there.

Why is the content not being Gzipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that this is a bug in Glassfish 3.1. It does not property split the `accept-encoding` header using the `,` character. For example, if you set firefox's `accept-encoding` header to: `gzip, deflate` it will not gzip the content because the comma screws it up, but if you set it to `gzip` then it does get gzipped by the server because there is no comma to choke on.  Apparently this has been fixed in Glassfish 3.1.1 but I have not tested it yet. See: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/gzip-compression-glassfish-3-doesnt-work?force=899 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the video.
I remember this came up before Glassfish 3.0 was released as a part of FishCAT.

I think the problem you are having is because you are only setting the one listener 'http-listener-1' and you need to set 'http-listener-2' as well.
(perhaps you did this, but did not show it in the video ?)

Comment: Why does it need to be enabled on both when I am only using the one listener? Is this a bug? My preliminary tests show that this didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

The same bug in Glassfish 3.1.2 and even 4.0 Beta - it looks like gzip compression has become completely buggy. Even if accept-encoding of firefox is set to solely gzip it doesn't work.
You might be using CompressionFilter from Google, but it is quitely difficult to use as it use a number of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issues with glassfish 3.1.2.2 and gzip.

Responses to HTTP requests in version 1.0 are not compressed. You must send your requests in **HTTP 1.1** to get gzipped responses from your glassfish server.

More over, you must add the header **"Accept-Encoding: gzip"** in your http requests.