# Glassfish 3.1 - 4.27 gzip HTTP Compression fails

Tags: java, glassfish, compression, gzip

I'm facing an issue with HTTP compression when using Glassfish 3.1 through 4.27. In general I have an impression it has never worked yet. Similar to the post here [Glassfish 3 - gzip compression does not work for .jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193374/glassfish-3-gzip-compression-does-not-work-for-jsp) I enabled the compression in the usual way by setting compression to 'on' and specifying either default types any other possible combinations. I have also tried this solution with 3.1 - no change (I check the results with Firebug's Page Speed and YSlow):

http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-979?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Does anyone face the same issue? I have been looking for over a for a solution, but nothing helps. These are the steps I already tried:
1) Testing compression with Glassfish 3.0.1, 3.1, 3.1.2 and 4b27 - always the same;
2) Testing with all kinds of combinations of mime type, e.g.: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript
3) The same tests while running Glassfish on java x32 and x64 different version, including the latest one: 1.6 update 31 and 1.7.03;
4) I also tried setting compression to force and setting the compression limit to 1, nothing helps.
Do you have any idea what could it be? I'm running Glassfish on Win7 with the latest Java x64 and x32 Bit. Has anyone accomplished any progress with this?

Comment: Just tested this on OSX/3.1.1 and 3.1.2 using the "on" method and mime type. Chrome reports it's gziped

Comment: Take a look at http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18446 I know you didn't specify that you have an apache and mod_jk in front of your glassfish server but maybe this bug will help you. It affects much more than what the initial bug was written up for. You can try the work around and see if it changes any of your results. Just copy the two grizzly jar's into your modules folder of your glassfish server..

Comment: Thanks Guys, your answers are very helpful, much appreciated. I haven'T been able to solve the problem anyway: I tested both proposed possibilities - no change. Tested the same application on Ubuntu and Glassfish 3.1.2, tested with a Sample application from NetBeans on Windows without any database connection - still no way to get it running. After nearly a month of search I give up ...